# Unable to see the Reset Security Token in my Salesforce org

Tags: permissions, security-token

I want to get the Security Token of my salesforce org. but the option is not visible in my org,

I have navigated to below path and checked, but i am not able to see that Option.

setup --> My settings --> personal --> My personal Information.

Their is no login IP ranges for my org.

How do I find out the Refresh security token.

Comment: Are any IP ranges specified in your user or profile? From documentation [Reset Your Security Token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&type=0), check if you are missing assigned permission- `Factor Authentication for API Logins`.

Answer (score 20):

Most likely it is because you are currently accessing from an IP that is within the Trusted IP Ranges (Setup -> Administer -> Security Controls -> Network Access) and Salesforce hides that option in that case.

That might explain why it is not displayed, but you can still access through the link. Just put `/_ui/system/security/ResetApiTokenEdit` after `https://......force.com`

Or... (while it still works the redirect if you don't have my-domain enabled and so on)

- https://login.salesforce.com/_ui/system/security/ResetApiTokenEdit for production / developer orgs
- https://test.salesforce.com/_ui/system/security/ResetApiTokenEdit for sandboxes

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact accessing from a Trusted IP as mentioned in the another answer, you can use an empty string as your access/security token as it isn't required for Trusted IPs in most cases (typically this is concatenated to your password, so you can use *just* your password). I found this particularly useful to remember for the Python library `simple_salesforce` when attempting to authenticate in a wrapper I'm working on to add some convenience methods for common operations for our "operators" aka admins.